# How to remove space between Grid and Button

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

[image]

I'm using Grid and Button to make an List of buttons.
This is my code

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
      BorderThickness="0" Background="Red" Content="dsa" Margin="0" Padding="0"/>
</Grid>
```

How to remove the space between the Grid with the Button ?

I tried to using padding & margin to 0, but it not affected.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the Margin of Button,like `Margin='-10'`. That will remove the space.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a style tag, and using border-collapse: collapse; and/or column-gap: 0px; ? (add these to the grid, not the button)

Comment: Thanks for you commenting. I fixed it. By editing the Button template, modify the template margin. ( Not the margin when the drag & drop from Toolbox. It's marin in Button template )

Comment: -1 on this answer for two reasons. a) It's a xaml issue and you're answering with css. b) Answering questions with "have you tried" or "what if" answers isn't an answer, keep it to a comment to help the OP better solicit attention to his question. Cheers!

Comment: a) I know it's XAML, and my initial thought was that styles are styles. If you're writing XAML, you're probably familiar enough with styles to convert to the <STYLE> template that XAML uses. b) Sometimes the best way to answer is to go into discovery mode. Hence the questions.

Comment: Thanks for all. Everybody rights. The ultimate goal is help our member & StackOverflow